# ffmpeg dont stop output on input finish

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding

I need help with behavior that is incomprehensible to me.
Ubuntu 20 system, compiled ffmpeg by Nvidia's GIT for CUDA support.
At the start of the conversion ffmpeg continues to write output indefinitely even beyond the duration of the input.

Here is the command used:

`/home/giulio/nvidia/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda  -i ~/360_3499.MP4 -i /home/giulio/gear360/l0000_x.tif -i /home/giulio/gear360/l0000_y.tif -loop 1 -i /home/giulio/gear360/Alpha_Map.tif -i /home/giulio/gear360/r0000_x.tif -i /home/giulio/gear360/r0000_y.tif -i /home/giulio/gear360/l0000.tif -i /home/giulio/gear360/r0000.tif -gpu 0 -vcodec h264_nvenc -preset p6 -tune hq -b:v 20M -bufsize 30M -maxrate 50M -qmin 0 -g 250 -bf 3 -b_ref_mode middle -temporal-aq 1 -rc-lookahead 20 -i_qfactor 0.75 -b_qfactor 1.1 -filter_complex [3]alphaextract[alf]; [v:0]scale=w=3840:h=-1:flags=lanczos,split=2[l][r]; [l][1][2]remap[l_remap]; [r][4][5]remap[r_remap]; [l_remap]setsar=sar=1/1[l_sar]; [r_remap]setsar=sar=1/1[r_sar]; [l_sar][6]blend=c0_mode=multiply[l_blend]; [r_sar][7]blend=c0_mode=multiply[r_blend]; [r_blend][alf]alphamerge[r_rm_a]; [l_blend][r_rm_a]overlay=0:0[merged]; [merged]eq=contrast=1.4:brightness=0.2:gamma=1.2:saturation=0.9[out] -map [out] -map 0:a? ~/360_3499-gpu.MP4`

Comment: Other information: No error reported with configure/compile/execution, same command with embedded ubuntu ffmpeg work fine

Comment: Other test: download and compiled from official GIT repository = same issue. other thinks, compiled version work fast 2X better that the builtin ubuntu version

Comment: When you want to bring more details to your initial question, it's better to edit the question rather than posting comments.

Comment: Your ffmpeg command is quite complex. Is it possible to find a minimal command that reproduce the problem? Also could post the terminal output of this command?